# AngularJS ng-options with object attributes value & title

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this array in my scope

```
$scope.containers = [{id: 1, title: "Icebox"}, {id: 2, title: "Summer"}, 
{id: 3, title: "Milestone"}];
```

Can I create something like this ng-options?

```
<option value="1">Icebox</option>
<option value="2">Summer</option>
<option value="3">Milestone</option>
```

Comment: It puts the index instead of v.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you are interested to show title use this way:

```
<select>
    <option
    ng-repeat="v in containers" 
    value="{{v.id}}" 
    title="{{v.title}}" 
    ng-selected="adresses.indexOf(v) == 0">{{v.title}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nF7eJ/50/)**</kbd>

But if you want only to show `value` `ng-options` will be enogh

Comment: Can't I do it with ng-options?

Comment: Works for me. But not an elegant solution.

Comment: but what about reading the value back and syncing with some scope model?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ng-options`

```
<select ng-options="v.id as v.title for v in containers" ng-model="selectedId">        
</select>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ncG5s/)**</kbd>

Comment: The OP says nothing about a tile attribute. He is only interested in how he can display the title from the object as label. So this is the correct answer. The "... as... for ... in ..." construction is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this same issue, where I was required to use ng-options, this was my solution...

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in vm.listOfItems">
    <option disabled>Select a value</option>
</select>
```

**Controller:**

```
vm.$onInit = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
         $("option").each(function (index, element) {
            var text = $(element).text();
            $(element).attr("title", text);
         });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this directive for showing title on options with ng-options.

```
angular.module("showTitle")
    .directive("showSelectTitle", ["$injector", showSelectTitle]);

function showSelectTitle($injector) {
    var $timeout = $injector.get("$timeout");
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $(element).find("option").each(function (index, elem) {
                    elem = $(elem);
                    var text = elem.text();
                    var truncated = text.substring(0, 30) + "...";
                    elem.attr("title", text);
                    elem.text(truncated);
                    elem.attr("label", truncated);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Use it like this

```
<select show-select-title ng-model="yourModel.Value" ng-options="value as label for yourArrayOfObjects"></select>
```

Hope it helps