# angular's ng-options with title

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am creating selection drop down using **ng-options** ,how can I use title attribute for options created by ng-option. My requirement is to give **title** attribute for options created by **ng-options**.

**Note**:I dont want to use **ng-repeat**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208976/how-to-set-title-attribute-for-option-elements-in-a-select-bound-to-a-model-with

Comment: I do not want ng-repeat over options to create option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52330473/2578840

Answer (score 2):

ngOptions doesn't currently support title. Instead,try using [select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)